# Update progress bar Value dynamically according to process pourcentage C#

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have created one application in which I am reading data from excel document. I am doing all time consuming task using background worker. How I can show how many percentage of work is done in progress bar?

I know that there is Report_Progress event is there but does it mean that I need specify hard coded value?

Is there any way by which I can get how many percent work is done out of total work?

**One example i want to specify like while copying how window showing its progress bar and it get increment as per the percentage of data copied.**

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to specify it.  It can't magically work out how far through you are.  You need to provide a [mcve] that shows your attempt and where you're stuck, this question is too broad as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{ 
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(yourprogress);
}

void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
             Messagebox.show(e.ProgressPercentage.toString())
             /// update you progressbar here with e.ProgressPercentage
             progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}
```

You can find another example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)

Comment: SamP - If you are updating a `DataContext` it would be simple to use it this way. Otherwise, if you are directly updating a UI control (which isn't advised), you will need to use the `Dispatcher` to invoke it over.